# Date picker library for react16

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

Is there any stable date picker library  for react 16 in which I can change month and year?

All the ones i found on npmjs website are either meant for react 15 or below  or does not have the facility to change month/year.

Thanks for any references.

Comment: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/

Comment: It uses html5's date input field instead of a dropdown calendar style datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [React16 Bootstrap Date Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-16-bootstrap-date-picker)

Comment: Have already tried that . The library is unstable. Throws errors randomly.